# What is tools:mockup, tools:mockup_crop and tools:mockup_opacity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tools-namespace

I just updated Android Studio to the version 2.3 (canary version) and to the last build tools `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha1'` and when I open a layout and write `tools:` and press `ctrl + space` to autocomplete it I found new tools namespaces :

```
tools:mockup
tools:mockup_crop
tools:mockup_opacity
```

I never see them before and search in google but I have found nothing.
What are the use of them?

Comment: is it related to android studio? I think it should related to platform & plugin updates

Comment: I think tools depend upon Api version but not on IDE. So tell me, which version of build tools and platform tools you are using?

Comment: You are right. `I using classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha1'`

Comment: I think it is related to the android studio [tools-attributes](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes) .

Comment: Of course pRaNaY, thats evident, but for what should be used?

Comment: I tried looking through the publicly available Android Studio source and the Tools source from android.googlesource.com, but I could not find sources for the canary version of Studio.

Comment: Perhaps we should mention some Google Android dev or @CommonsWare

Comment: They also have "tools:targetApi" . What is it for?

Comment: Also, just a guess about the purpose of the mockup: maybe Google considered this request: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=228538

Comment: @androiddeveloper targetApi is a ""supress warning" anotation in the XML to avoid have warnigs in the XML when you put params like elevation that are not supported in all versions. With that you can remove the warning

Comment: @Aracem Yes I noticed it. But I wonder what the rest are for. Like "mockup" for example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's for a feature we're working on but which isn't part of Studio yet. This part was accidentally not put behind a flag (which normally removes it during compilation.)  We just fixed it; next canary won't show these items -- until the feature is enabled when it's done.

Comment: Is it out now? If it is what is it for?

Comment: I still see this `tools:mockup`, can you point to a documentation? can't find any.

Comment: So 2.3 is released already and this attributes is still visible in auto-completion. What is this feature exactly?

Comment: FYI @Tor Norbye, continue appearing in Android Studio 2.3 and 2.4preview1

Comment: @tor-norbye Any update on this? I didn't see any news on this Google I/O 17